# Jinja 2 Template Syntax Error -- jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: python, jinja2, pymysql

Getting a template syntax error when trying to retrieve data from a database and display on webpage. Don't understand why because all Jinja syntax checks out.

Here's the html/jinja

```
<table>
{% for row in search %}
        <tr>
        <th> ID </th>
                <td> {{row['hostname'] }}</td>
        <th> hostName </th>
                <td> {{ row['ID'] }}</td>
        <th> reportName </th>
                <td>{{ row['reportName'] }} </td>
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what the error is saying:

```
 File "/home/ttataryn/FlaskApp/templates/result.html", line 631, in template
    {% endfor %}
TemplateSyntaxError: Unexpected end of template. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'.
```

And here is where i query the database to retrieve those items:

```
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        query = ("SELECT * FROM StoryData WHERE hostName LIKE '%s'")
        print(query)
        cursor.execute(query % (result))
        search = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in search:
                ID = row['ID']
                hName = row['hostName']
                rName = row['reportName']

        return render_template("result.html", search=search)
        connection.close()
```

Comment: It's possible you misused Jinja somewhere earlier in the template, syntax of this  part looks good.

Comment: That's just the problem. I'm just trying to test it out and start from ground zero. All I have is the starting HTML code -- html, body, etc. Nothing else is in there... where else could i be wrong?